# ajax paginate failed while sending data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
$(function(){
    $("select").change(function(event){
        var showlist = $(this).find("option:selected");
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            dataType:"json",
            url:"{:url('Number/lst')}",
            data:{showlist:showlist},
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
        alert(showlist);
    });
});
```

I use form  method to do paginate but I can't get the value that user choose to PHP. I can use alert showlist to get value.

PHP receive:

```
$showlist=input('showlist');
echo $showlist;
$list=Numberlist::paginate($showlist);
```

Comment: if I have understand your quesion , you can pass the value in the url and get it with $_GET['value']

Comment: how can you use json array as the url ?

Comment: thanks for the reply. i use datatable to solve many problem ady.